# How can I deploy vue.js app on shared host?

Tags: vue.js, deployment

I build a website with vue.js and use `lokalise` for language switch.
So, when I enter my app address, like example.com, it becomes example.com/en. This is ok when I type example.com for the first time, it becomes example.com/en and shows the website, but if I refresh the current link (example.com/en) it shows 404 error. And if I type example.com/fa which is another language I use in my app, it shows 404 error, too. But these all are correct on my local server and there is no error.

If you want to test it on my website, check this site: [my website](http://hamidyaftian.ir)

Comment: It seems like you are using vue to route to "/en" and "/fa"... if so your nginx / apache nicht not recognize that this is not a "real" route but handled by vue. Maybe try using a hash-router?

Comment: these two route (/en and /fa) are created by "lokalise" package and managed by it. I didn't create them in vue-router.

Comment: how can I use hash-router?